# WebDriverWait in static mode

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I have piece of code

```
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("map_background_3d")));
```

When it's executed as test ng test it works ok. Now I want to create executable jar and moved my code to main method and when I run it from there it fails with:

```
    Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of element located by By.id: map_background_3d (tried for 60 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)
at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.timeoutException(WebDriverWait.java:81)
at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:271)
at Tkt.lookForTickets(Tkt.java:83)
at Tkt.main(Tkt.java:34)                                               
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Cannot locate an element using By.id: map_background_3d
```

I don't get it.

Comment: Why do you want `visibility`? What do you want to do next with the returned element?

Comment: visibilityOfElementLocated instead of this use presence of element , It might work for you !

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly why you're getting this error, but I can guide you on how to investigate it yourself:

First, if you're using Chrome on headless mode, I suggest that you (temporarily) remove that, so you can see what happens. Second, as selenium itself is not aware (and shouldn't be affected) if it runs s part of test ng or an executable, then if you see a difference in the UI, then you're probably doing something different in your code. (Could be that you do some stuff in the `@Before` method which you forgot to move to your `main`?)

Now, try to see if the element you're looking for is actually visible or not. If it's not, put a breakpoint in your code, and when you expect to see that element but you don't, open the Dev Tools (by pressing F12), and search (Ctrl+F) for `#map_background_3d`. If the element is found it means that the element exists, but is not visible, otherwise it means that tree element does not exists. In either case, try eliminating the differences between the test ng and the executable code to find the root cause.

If you *are* able to identify the element visually, then you probably have its `id` wrong. Try to identify it again using the Dev Tools.

Note that even though there shouldn't be more than one element with the same id on the sane page, browsers don't enforce it and it can actually be. If this is the case, you may find more than one element with the id your looking for, and if the first one of those is not visible (even though the 2nd is) you may still get this error.

HTH...